# How can i get the size of layout dynamically in android

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I am adding text view to linear layout such that in samsung s2 it is working fine and in samsung s3 device layout height is reduced.I am finding the layout height but i am not getting

Comment: paste your layout file

Comment: If any answer was useful, please mark as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Just get the view tree observer from the layout and attach a listener to it. Now inside it, you can get its height or width, and you just have to deattach the global layout listener. Just note that for android sdk > 16 you must use mContainer.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

```
private ViewGroup mContainer;

@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        final ViewTreeObserver observer = mContainer.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int layoutHeight = mContainer.getHeight();
                rowHeight = layoutHeight / getResources().getInteger(R.integer.rows);
                mContainer.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                    mContainer.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are adding any views dynamically to a parent, then you can
   adjust it by using gravity, weight, etc. so that it can be
   compatible to all the resolutions.Never give hard code values.
2. You asked that to get height of a layout, that can be done using
   getHeight().